# What are the access specifiers in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have come from c++ and java background so, I was curious to know if python provides access specifiers as provided by c++/java. I've seen some code, and this is what I think, 
__variable ---> private.
_variable ----> protected.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Python has recommended practices rather than prescriptive ones - so anything with a `_` at the start ***should*** be left alone by others but is **not** locked to prevent it.  There is however name mangling to make life more interesting for members with a `__` at the start - see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

Of course if others rely on your private data/methods rather then the public API they only have themselves to blame when you change something and their code stops working.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept in Python.  There are conventions that are used - like the ones Steve mentioned but also others such as calling the first variable of an instance method `self`.

In addition, for module level imports - there is a way to prevent the default behavior of importing all names from a module. This is done by populating `__all__` with a list of names that should be imported (exposed) by default.

However, as with `__var` and `_var` it is just a convention (although one that is enforced by Python). It doesn't restrict you though - you can explicitly import any name.